# $(window).width() and $(window).height() return NULL -JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the size of browser window using `$(window).width()` and `$(window).height()` functions. However this two return null. the `$(window)` is not null, it's returning "object".
I have tried also using `$(document).width()` and `$(document).height()`, this two do not return null, they are returning specific values, but they are bigger than the window size. Any idea why the `$window` 2 values are null?

```
$(window).load(function () {

            var view = $("#view");
            var image = $("#image");
            var hiResImage = $("#hi-res-image"); 
            var zoom = $("<a id='zoom'><span><br /></span></a>");
            log("ERROR 1 = " + $(window).width());
            log("ERROR 1 = " + $(window).height());
            log("ERROR 1 = " + $(window));
            image.width($(window).width());
            image.height($(window).height());
```

.....

Should I initialize somw how the $(window) variable?

Comment: I just ran it in Firebug, and it worked.  .width() returns 1349.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of jQuery?

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for you, but `$(document)` and `$(window)` return equal values for width and height.

Comment: They work just fine for me in the browser I'm currently using.  Can you post the code you've got that convinces you otherwise?

Comment: I am missing a lot of information, browser, jQuery version, etc. Your code should work fine, though I read somewhere on the internet you need jQuery v1.2+. So please check that.

Comment: This reads more like a comment, than an answer. :)

Comment: How are "Your code should work fine" and "you need jQuery v1.2+" not answers to the questions "Why doesn't my code work" and "why the $window 2 values are null?"

Comment: "Your code should work" does not answer the question of why it *doesn't* work (I agree that it *should*, but it apparently *doesn't*); "you need jQuery v1.2+" is potentially an answer, though supporting that with "I read somewhere on the internet" makes it *feel* more like a comment. My response isn't to suggest that this is *not* an answer, more that it *reads* like a comment.

Comment: I am using latest JQuery with mozilla 3.5.18

Comment: $(window).load(function () {var view = $("#view");
                var image = $("#image");
                var hiResImage = $("#hi-res-image"); var zoom = $("<a id='zoom'><span><br /></span></a>");
                log("ERROR 1 = " + $(window).width());
                log("ERROR 1 = " + $(window).height());
                log("ERROR 1 = " + $(window));
                image.width($(window).width());
                image.height($(window).height());

Comment: mozilla 3.5.18 with JQuery 1.5

Comment: have you tried the so-called 'vanilla' javascript that I and another poster suggested?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { ` instead of window.load, because the window may have loaded and this will be fired before the entire page is loaded (for example images won't be loaded yet).

Answer (score 6):

Just like commenters, I'm not sure why that doesn't work, but this can be done in vanilla JS and the window object without jQuery so you might have better luck with that.  Could circumvent some issues with jQuery versions, browser compatability, etc

```
window.innerWidth   //just the actual document window
window.innerHeight
window.outerWidth   //includes brother toolbars, status bar, etc
window.outerHeight
```

I'd still recommend you investigate why what you oroginally tried isnt working, bc whatever the root problem is it will probably manifest itself again elsewhere.

Comment: $(window).load(function () {var view = $("#view");
                var image = $("#image");
                var hiResImage = $("#hi-res-image"); var zoom = $("<a id='zoom'><span><br /></span></a>");
                log("ERROR 1 = " + $(window).width());
                log("ERROR 1 = " + $(window).height());
                log("ERROR 1 = " + $(window));
                image.width($(window).width());
                image.height($(window).height());

Comment: thats pretty rough to read, can you post it to the bottom of your question?

Answer (score 2):

I played around on the console in Google Chrome and the following works for me:

```
$(window).attr('screen').height
```

and

```
$(window).attr('screen').width
```

**EDIT**: See jon_darkstar's answer. The `$(window)` function is a jQuery selector which returns a DOM element. In order to access the properties of the object you need to use the `.attr()` method. I tend to agree with jon_darkstar, Occam's Razor dictates that vanilla JS is most probably the best way to go, and thus gets my vote. But if you **really** want to use jQuery, the above will work.

Comment: This is wrong for two reasons: first, it actually gives the wrong results (you are accessing `window.screen`, which is data about the screen the window is on, not the window itself); and second, it is an odd exploitation of a misconception in jQuery that attributes and properties are the same thing (they're not). `window` does not have attributes, as it is not an element; jQuery defaults to properties where attributes don't exist, potentially creating this sort of confusion. Edit: it's also wrong to say that jQuery doesn't support `$(window).width()` etc.